# How to separate a ul with 30 item to 3 row?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a php code that generates a ul with 30 li I want to show this ul in 3 rows. Please tell me what should I do?

```
 <?php  
     $args = array( 'hide_empty' => false, );

    $terms = get_terms( 'job_region', $args );
   if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
$count = count( $terms );
$i = 0;
$all_count=wp_count_posts('job');
$published_jobs = $all_count->publish;
$term_list = '<ul class="statelist"><li class="all" count-all= ' . $published_jobs . '><a href="http://estekhdamia.com/job-listings/" title="تمام آگهی ها">تمام استان ها</a></li></ul><ul class="statelist clearfix">';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    $i++;
    $term_list .= '<li class=' . $term->slug . ' count-all=' . $term->count . '><a href="/job-search/?location=' . $term->slug . '&submit=true" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'نمایش آگهی های %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    if ( $count != $i ) {
        $term_list .= " ";
    }
    else {
        $term_list .= '</ul>';
    }
}
echo $term_list;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: A: bootstrap it or use a modulus.

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you mean 3 columns? Provide sample of expected results

Comment: insert a closing and opening ul tag each 10 counts in your loop, if it is to spray in 3 col, column(-count -balance) css might do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using styles:

```css
ul li {
    display: inline;
    
}
ul li:nth-child(10n):after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>01</li>
  <li>02</li>
  <li>03</li>
  <li>04</li>
  <li>05</li>
  <li>06</li>
  <li>07</li>
  <li>08</li>
  <li>09</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: seems to me copy paste with the modification for row (rather than column which is done below)

Comment: for info, the column approach for either row or column : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObWZRv ;)

Comment: @Anant, Hi, man. I don't use and I don't understand what is `flex` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a purely CSS-based solution (ie, you can output the list as a completely regular list, and show it like this). This does however work on the basis that you know the content, and can set a height.

```css
#columns {
  display: flex;
     flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 10em;
  }
#rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 40em;
  }
li {
  height: 1em;
  width: 4em;
  list-style-position: inside;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="columns">
  <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
    <li>Item 16</li>
    <li>Item 17</li>
    <li>Item 18</li>
    <li>Item 19</li>
      <li>Item 20</li>
    <li>Item 21</li>
    <li>Item 22</li>
    <li>Item 23</li>
    <li>Item 24</li>
    <li>Item 25</li>
    <li>Item 26</li>
    <li>Item 27</li>
    <li>Item 28</li>
    <li>Item 29</li>
    <li>Item 30</li>
  </ul>

<ul id="rows">
  <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
    <li>Item 16</li>
    <li>Item 17</li>
    <li>Item 18</li>
    <li>Item 19</li>
      <li>Item 20</li>
    <li>Item 21</li>
    <li>Item 22</li>
    <li>Item 23</li>
    <li>Item 24</li>
    <li>Item 25</li>
    <li>Item 26</li>
    <li>Item 27</li>
    <li>Item 28</li>
    <li>Item 29</li>
    <li>Item 30</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: no I want 3 rows not 3 columns !

Comment: Ah, let me fix. That will, however, mean that you need to know the width of the elements for this solution to work.

Comment: +10. for your effort. The correct answer seems copy-paste with the modification (for row not column,which you missed)

Comment: It's a different solution, and works just as well :)

Comment: @Anant , Columns works, but rows doesn't. Look at snippet full screen. Downvote?

Comment: Sorry about that, snuck in an error in the CSS (min-width instead of just width) - fixed now.